# First steps with Celery using a virtualenv

Tags: python, celery, virtualenv

I'm just doing my first steps using Celery. I created a small example which is based on the steps described at http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html When I try to start the worker manually using

```
celery -A my_example worker --loglevel=info
```

I run in an error because a module from my virtualenv cannot be found. The virtualenv is activated and the module is installed, so I assume that celery is using my global python interpreter. I checked

```
celery worker --help
```

but found no parameter to specify a certain interpreter or virtualenv. Could somebody tell my how to start a worker manually inside a virtualenv?

**Update:**

I had Celery installed in my global python environment and in my virtualenv. I removed both and double checked that both versions are removed. I then installed Celery i my virutalenv. If I now call the `celery` comand line tool, it get the following error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/celery: No such file or directory
```

That's the location where the tool would be installed to, if it would be installed globaly. So does Celery work at all from a virtualenv?

Comment: what is giving you celery.__file__ ?

(project_A)user-164-126-78-15:~ galuszkak$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep  7 2013, 11:38:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import celery
>>> celery.__file__
'/Users/galuszkak/Projects/virtuals/project_A/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__init__.pyc'

Comment: If I do this from an interactive prompt, I get the path to the virtualenv version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tried to cleanly install celery in virtualenv (without installing it in global system interpreter):

```
mkdir celery-test
cd celery-test
virtualenv-2.7 .python
source .python/bin/activate
pip install celery
celery worker --help
```

It works perfectly, `which celery` gives me:

```
/home/user/projects/celery-test/.python/bin/celery
```

As expected.

I suggesting you to rerun your terminal session (possible problems with PATH).

If it does not help, then you can inspect your PATH variable to find, why celery from virtualenv not visible.

And if there are no problems with PATH, but problem persists, try to recreate your virtualenv from scratch.

**EDIT:**

Another suggestion: check output of:

```
which celery
```

It should point to some path, but also it could be aliased like that:

```
celery: aliased to /somepath/bin/celery
```

If it actually aliased to something, than you need to check your `~/.bashrc` (`~/.zshrc`) or `~/.bash_profile` (`~/.zprofile`), or even contents of `/etc/profile.d/*` folder. You need to get rid of this alias.

Comment: Looks like it was the PATH. A new terminal session solved the problem. But I have no idea why!? ;-)

Comment: @Achim, glad your problem is solved :) I don't know, just suggested. Maybe something installed in this terminal session was mangling with PATH, so /usr/local/bin was at the begining of PATH.

Comment: Had the same problem. I installed celery for the original python and for the virtualenv python. After I activated the virtual env, venv/bin/ has been added to the front of $PATH, and celery is in venv/bin/ directory, too. Somehow, `which celery` still gave `usr/local/bin/celery`, until I uninstalled celery from the original python. I think your words `without installing it in global system interpreter` is quite important, but not sure why. `alias celery=venv/bin/celery` didn't work, either